# Why are HTTP requests ignored?

Tags: http, openbsd

I have the following network:

· openbsd 5.0 web server (LAN)
· windows 7 (LAN)
· router provided by my ISP (LAN, WAN)
· cell phone not conected to the network (WAN)

*UPDATE*
As LAN I mean a home network with 192.168.1.x addresses, so openbsd and windows are here. As WAN I mean Internet or public IP. With that the router is the point of connection between internet and my house.

My web application is coded in python and using cherrypy as web framework. From windows machine I can see the web pages and navigate from home to all pages served by openbsd. That means all is working perfectly on home network web requests.

The next step I did is opened the router ports to reach the web server from the outside. Before redirecting to openbsd machine I made a test using my windows machine as the web server and works fine using my cell phone as the client (meaning that from internet can reach the window machine). Changing the redirection from windows to openbsd server broke the internet access but from home network all is fine.

So, my problem is that I cannot reach the openbsd from internet. I don't know what is happening but I though that openbsd is rejecting external connections. I googled about that and find some links about pf but is disabled on my openbsd. I've also found how to get information using netstat tool and when I make a request from internet don't show anything but when requests are from home network is showing all connections.

My questions are:

- How can I know if there are incoming connections from internet?
- Is there any tool other than pf that can block external connections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many routers can't forward port 80 because their administrative interface runs on that port. You may be able to get it to work by changing the port the router's web interface runs on.

Comment: I configured the router to listen on port 8080 and send to openbsd machine to port 80. The port 80 of the router is for administrative tasks. The same configuration is what I've used on windows machine but using port 8060 as external. In this case, the redirection is doing correctly and serves pages.

Comment: So what's the difference between the cases that work and the cases that don't work?

Comment: If I make a request from a machine in the internal side (192.168.1.x) the openbsd serves the page, but on the out side (213.14.51.189 for example) serves nothing.

Comment: You are leaving out all the details. For example, does "in the internal side" mean *to* the internal address of the server or from an internal address of another machine? Which ports are you accessing on the router and which on the machine? Has access from the outside of your LAN *ever* worked?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll try to explain better. The router is the point to communicate to Internet. From the router to internet I mean as external side. From router to all devices conected to it I mean as internal side. The internal side is a simple home network using 192.168.1.x addresses. OpenBsd server and Windows machine are on the internal side. My cell phone is on the external side.

Comment: Please post the solution separately as an answer, instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the port used on the router. The number 8080 has to be reserved for something I don't know. I've changed it for 8010 and work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try a

```
netstat -tunl
```

to show all listening sockets (I guess it should work on openbsd), you might want to check if web server is running (port 80).
As said above, double-check your NAT translation (on your router -> 80 -> openbsdip:80

Double-check about pf too, you may have some server firewalls rules (deny all from outside lan)

Comment: I'm so thankful about your answer. It gaves me the idea of what could be happen and I found it. It is not a problem with openbsd but the router. It seems that port 8080 is reserved for any reason I don't know. I've changed it and it works perfectly.

Comment: You'll see that netstat will be handy when having such issues in the future ! ;) Happy to read that it helped !